# Powershell - Remove-Item not working on multiple iterations - Invalid Path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to backup tables in my database, then copy those bak files to another server. If there are multiple copies of the same database, I am leaving only one copy (newest one).

Tables to backup are in array, so I am looping through them. On first iteration, everything works as expected, .bak file is created, copied to server, old copies are deleted, only leaving 2 bak files (one copy and new one), but on next iteration I get "Invalid Path" exception.

Error is raised on this line: Remove-Item -LiteralPath $fileToRemove -Force , with exception Invalid Path: Invalid Path: '\remoteServer\BACKUP\BACKUP\database\table2_20230911_160158.bak'

Every file that is second in iteration, gets this exception.

```
      # Set variables
    $BackupDir = "D:\Backup\Backup_Job"
    $RemoteBackupDir = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\remoteServer\BACKUP\BACKUP"
    $Timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"
    $ServerInstances = @{
        "database" = @("table1,table2")
    }
    $LogPath = "D:\Backup\Logs.txt"
    
    "BackupStarted - $Timestamp" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $LogPath
    
    if (!(Test-Path $BackupDir)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $BackupDir
    }

    try
    {
        foreach($databaseName in $ServerInstances.Keys)
    {
        
    $backupFolder = "$BackupDir\$databaseName"
    $remoteBackupFolder ="$RemoteBackupDir\$databaseName"
    if (!(Test-Path $backupFolder)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $backupFolder
    }
    if (!(Test-Path $remoteBackupFolder)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $remoteBackupFolder
    }
    foreach($tableName in $ServerInstances.$databaseName)
    {
      #Files are named "Table1_$Timestamp" so we are searching for all files that contain table name
      $filesToDelete = Get-ChildItem -Path "$remoteBackupFolder" -Filter "$tableName*.bak"
      #Sort them by creation time     
      $sortedFilesToDelete = $filesToDelete | Sort-Object CreationTime
      #number of copies to keep
      $numberOfCopiesToKeep = 1
     #amount of files to remove
     $filesToRemove = $sortedFilesToDelete.Count - $numberOfCopiesToKeep
     for ($i = 0; $i -lt $filesToRemove; $i++) {
     
            if($sortedFilesToDelete.Count -gt $numberOfCopiesToKeep)
            {
                $fileToRemove = $sortedFilesToDelete[$i].FullName
                "$fileToRemove" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $LogPath
                #here is where error is occuring after second iteration of foreach above
                Remove-Item -LiteralPath $fileToRemove -Force
                
            }   
        }
    $backupFilePath = "${backupFolder}\${tableName}_${Timestamp}.bak"
    $remoteFilePath = "${remoteBackupFolder}\${tableName}_${Timestamp}.bak"
    "$databaseName $tableName $backupFilePath" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $LogPath
    Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $databaseName -Database $tableName -BackupFile $backupFilePath
    Copy-Item -Path $backupFilePath -Destination $remoteFilePath -Force
    }
}
Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir -Recurse| Foreach-object {Remove-item -Recurse -path $_.FullName }
}
catch{
    $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    "Error - $($_.Exception.Message) - Date- $Timestamp - Line- $line" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $LogPath
}
finally{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir -Recurse| Foreach-object {Remove-item -Recurse -path $_.FullName }
}
```

Comment: Is database SQL Server.   See this issue before.  When a database is attached to the server the server owns the mdf file.  The only way of solving the issue is to deattach the mdf file from the server.  Then copy the mdf file for backup.  The reattach the mdf file to the server.  Doing anything else changes the windows permissions on the mdf file and then you need an admin to correct the permissions.

Comment: Database is Microsoft SQL Server. Didn't understand your answer, I create backup files (.bak) without problem on first iteration, but next iteration it breaks on remove-item, it should not have anything with database.

Comment: You cannot delete the mdf file if it is still attached to the database.  If you want to delete you first have to deattach.

Comment: Which line of code is raising the exception? Can you include the full error message... Also, it might be easier to debug if you indent your code consistently throughout - you've currently got code inside a nested ```foreach``` which is indented at the same level as the parent ```try```

Comment: This line is raising exception : Remove-Item -LiteralPath $fileToRemove -Force , with exception Invalid Path: '\remoteServer\BACKUP\BACKUP\database\table2_20230911_160158.bak', but if you set that table2 is first in iteration, then it will not throw that exception.